# Apss Script the "if" condition is evaluated incorrectly

Tags: google-apps-script

oldnames[i+3]='Tom'
newnames[i]='Tom'

Why my code bellow is going through when both parameters have the same value (see above)?

```
for (var i=0 ; i<pocet2 ; i++) {
      var oldnaz=(oldnames[i+3]).toString();
      var newnaz=(newnames[i]);
      oldnaz=oldnaz.toString();
      newnaz=newnaz.toString();
      //Logger.log("oldname = "+oldnaz);
      //Logger.log("newname = "+newnaz);
      
      if(newnames[i]=='' )
      {
        //Logger.log(ss.getSheetByName(oldnames[i+3]).getSheetName());
        //Logger.log(i);
        //Logger.log(i+3);
        ss.getSheetByName(oldnames[i+3]).setName((i+1).toString());
      }
**      else if(newnames[i] != oldnames[i+3])
      {
      //Logger.log(newnames[i]);
      //Logger.log(oldnames[i+3]);
      ss.getSheetByName(oldnames[i+3]).setName(newnames[i]);
      }**
      else
      {
        //Nothing
      }
  }
```

I tried few changes in code, but the result was in all ways: the condition is TRUE.
But when 1st value is Tom and 2nd is Tom, then else if(Tom != Tom) should be FALSE.
Many thanks for tip.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]  your code is not reproducible

Comment: TheMaster solved it. Problem was that I didnt pointed at the "right column" in the array row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `oldnames` and `newnames` are from a range using `range.getValues()`, then both those variables are two dimensional arrays and not a one dimensional array.
As such, `oldnames[i+3]='Tom' newnames[i]='Tom'` is false, it would be

```
oldnames[i+3]=['Tom']; //array
newnames[i]=['Tom'];
```

```js
const newname=['Tom'];
const oldname=['Tom'];
console.log(newname != oldname);//expected true
```

Two arrays cannot be compared. Get the string inside and compare:

```
else if(newnames[i][0] !== oldnames[i+3][0])
```

Comment: Good advice. Problem solved. Now I know, how arrays work. TheMaster, thank you very much.

Comment: @Zaskar Glad to help. Consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer.